# How to properly upload files

Tags: primefaces

I have a problem with file upload. I have a page, where there is an output box. And if I need to make more then 1 mP (myProduct for example) and I add the same section all look OK. But when I fill first mP and add next, the file uploaded in first section in not OK. If I choose file in first section, and click to upload, get error "The file was not choosed"....Some tips how to solve it? btw: sorry for my english

```
    <div class="ShadowBox whiteback RedBorderedBox ui-fluid">
        <div class="CI">
            <p:outputPanel styleClass="C100">
                <h1 class="BT">#{msg.mP}</h1>
                <div class="C100">
                    <p:dataList id="#{id}_mPList"
                                value="#{mPs}" var="rec" 
                                type="definition" emptyMessage="No data">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="8" layout="grid"
                                     style="border:0px !important; background:none;"
                                     styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank"
                                     columnClasses="ui-grid-col-5, ui-grid-col-5">
                            <p:inputTextarea placeholder="#{msg.mPPro}"
                                             value="#{rec.p}" disabled="#{MyBean.locked}"
                                             rows="1">
                                <p:ajax listener="#{MyBean.inv()}" update="@(.buttonPanelClass)"
                                        event="change"/>
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                            <p:fileUpload value="#{MyBean.modFile}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" label="Choose file"
                               update="#{id}_mPList @(.buttonPanelClass)" />

                            <p:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{MyBean.saveModFile(rec, modCat)}" ajax="false"
                               update="#{id}_mPList @(.buttonPanelClass)" icon="fa fa-arrow-up green"/>

                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton immediate="true"
                                             update="#{id}_mPList @(.buttonPanelClass)"
                                             action="#{MyBean.addMedProduct(medProducts)}"
                                             value="#{msg.add}"
                                             disabled="#{MyBean.locked}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dataList>
                </div>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </div>
    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I can't see your h:form, but check that you have this attribute on it <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: yes, this is OK.

Comment: The problem is I think the same ID, or the same variable, but I am not sure :(

Comment: Then make sure... simplify... but also make it complete  [mcve]. Waaay to much code in your question

Comment: Now it is OK? Thanks for your support

Comment: Of removing the styleclasses, style, divs, h1 makes it work it is partially ok because there is no bean to help it reproduce. And just copy paste in anmpty project to try